# Code generation from WSDL causes exception

Tags: java, wsdl, code-generation, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I'm using Axis2 1.5.1 (wsdl2java) for code generation (client stubs) from a given WSDL file.
The webservice is provided by an external application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"  
xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility- 1.0.xsd"  
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"   
xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"             
xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/"   
xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"     
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" 
xmlns:i0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/02/mex/bindings" 
xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" 
xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" 
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/"   
xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"   
xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex"   
name="service" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/"   
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">  
<wsdl:types>  
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">  
<xsd:include schemaLocation="SampleApp.App.ApplicationManager.RemoteApplication0.xsd" />  
<xsd:include schemaLocation="SampleApp.App.ApplicationManager.RemoteApplication1.xsd" />  
<xsd:include schemaLocation="SampleApp.App.ApplicationManager.RemoteApplication2.xsd" />  
<xsd:include schemaLocation="SampleApp.App.ApplicationManager.RemoteApplication3.xsd" />  
</xsd:schema>  
</wsdl:types>  
...  
</wsdl:definition>
```

Content of RemoteApplication0.xsd is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message" 
elementFormDefault="qualified"  
targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message"  
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">  
<xs:complexType name="MessageBody">  
<xs:sequence>  
<xs:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="##any" />  
</xs:sequence>  
</xs:complexType>  
</xs:schema>
```

commandline:

```
wsdl2java -ss -g -d adb -or -p com.sampleapp.ws.generated.client -uri SampleRemoteProcess.wsdl
```

Generation process causes an exception.
stacktrace:

```
Using AXIS2_HOME: C:\develop\axis2-1.5.1-bin\axis2-1.5.1\
Using JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21
Retrieving document at 'C:\temp\SampleRemoteProcess.wsdl'.
Retrieving schema at 'SampleApp.App.ApplicationManager.RemoteApplication0.xsd', relative to 'file:/C:/temp/SampleRemoteProcess.wsdl'.
Retrieving schema at 'SampleApp.App.ApplicationManager.RemoteApplication1.xsd', relative to 'file:/C:/temp/SampleRemoteProcess.wsdl'.
Retrieving schema at 'SampleApp.App.ApplicationManager.RemoteApplication2.xsd', relative to 'file:/C:/temp/SampleRemoteProcess.wsdl'.
Retrieving schema at 'SampleApp.App.ApplicationManager.RemoteApplication3.xsd', relative to 'file:/C:/temp/SampleRemoteProcess.wsdl'.
[ERROR] org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException:  

An included schema was announced to have the default target namespace  
or the target namespace http://tempuri.org/Imports,  
but has the target namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message  
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException:  
An included schema was announced to have the default target namespace  
or the target namespace http://tempuri.org/Imports, but has the target namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:1904)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:1927)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleInclude(SchemaBuilder.java:1653)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:219)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:433)  
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder.getXMLSchema(WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder.java:144)  
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.copyExtensibleElements(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:2319)  
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.processTypes(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:413)  
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.processTypes(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:402)  
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateService(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:346)  
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.populateAllServices(WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.java:107)  
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(CodeGenerationEngine.java:147)  
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)  
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)  
Caused by: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException:  
An included schema was announced to have the default target namespace  
or the target namespace http://tempuri.org/Imports  
but has the target namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder$2.validate(SchemaBuilder.java:1679)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.setNamespaceAttributes(SchemaBuilder.java:369)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:134)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.build(SchemaBuilder.java:121)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:445)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:368)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:1898)  
... 13 more  

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: Error parsing WSDL  
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(CodeGenerationEngine.java:153)  
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Code.main(WSDL2Code.java:35)  
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java.main(WSDL2Java.java:24)  
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault:  
org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException:  
An included schema was announced to have the default target namespace  
or the target namespace http://tempuri.org/Imports,  
but has the target namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message  
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)  
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateService(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:396)  
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.populateAllServices(WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder.java:107)  
at org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationEngine.(CodeGenerationEngine.java:147)  
... 2 more    

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:  
org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaException:  
An included schema was announced to have the default target namespace  
or the target namespace http://tempuri.org/Imports,  
but has the target namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:1904)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:1927)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleInclude(SchemaBuilder.java:1653)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:219)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:433)  
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder.getXMLSchema(WSDLToAxisServiceBuilder.java:144)  
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.copyExtensibleElements(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:2319)  
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.processTypes(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:413)  
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.processTypes(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:402)  
at org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.populateService(WSDL11ToAxisServiceBuilder.java:346)  
... 4 more  

An included schema was announced to have the default target namespace  
or the target namespace http://tempuri.org/Imports,  
but has the target namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder$2.validate(SchemaBuilder.java:1679)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.setNamespaceAttributes(SchemaBuilder.java:369)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.handleXmlSchemaElement(SchemaBuilder.java:134)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.build(SchemaBuilder.java:121)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:445)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.XmlSchemaCollection.read(XmlSchemaCollection.java:368)  
at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.SchemaBuilder.resolveXmlSchema(SchemaBuilder.java:1898)  
... 13 more
```

Seems there is a namespace problem, but i dont know how to fix it.
Can anybody give me a hint!

Answer (score 3):

the problem is your use of "include".  "include"ed schemas must have the *same* target namespace as the schema in which the include resides (you are esentially splitting the same namespace across multiple files).  you must "import" a schema to use another schema file with a *different* target namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty descriptive: A schema that is `<include>`'ed in another schema always needs to have the same target namespace as the importing schema. In the file RemoteApplication0.xsd you have to change the target namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message` to `http://tempuri.org/Imports`.

Comment: I already tried it! But i still get an exception:  
  
An included schema was announced to have the default target namespace or 
the target namespace http://tempuri.org/Imports, 
but has the target namespace http://tempuri.org/

Comment: So? This is the same error. You have to provide `http://tempuri.org/Imports`, __not__ `http://tempuri.org` or something similar.

Comment: I did use `http://tempuri.org/Imports`! But the exception message is `http://tempuri.org/`.  I'm totally confused!

Comment: Me too. Could you try with `wsimport` (comes with every JDK) instead of `wsdl2java`? If there still is some error, maybe you could update your question. I don't know why parts of a namespace should be stripped.

Comment: @jtahlborn: You are right (and it took a while till somebody found out) and I edited the answer accordingly.