# URI unbound for wsdl file

Tags: java, apache-axis, wsdl2java

I have tried searching the net for the issue but i am unable to find a soultion.

I have a wsdl file.

This wsdl file has 2 xsd:schema defined.

One of the xsd:schema is being imported inside another one.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wsdl:definitions name="identityService"
targetNamespace="http://ws.identityService.bls.risk.dummy.com/"
xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat"   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:tns="http://ws.identityService.bls.risk.dummy.com/"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified"
        elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ns.dummy.com/identity-service/1.0"
        version="9.0" xmlns:identity="http://ns.dummy.com/identity-service/1.0"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">



    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
        elementFormDefault="unqualified"
        targetNamespace="http://ws.identityService.bls.risk.dummy.com/"
        xmlns:ns0="http://ns.dummy.com/identity-service/1.0"  xmlns:tns="http://ws.identityService.bls.risk.dummy.com/"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://ns.dummy.com/identity-service/1.0" />
        <xsd:element name="invokeIdentityService" type="tns:invokeIdentityService" />

    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="invokeIdentityServiceResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:invokeIdentityServiceResponse" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="invokeIdentityService">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:invokeIdentityService" name="parameters">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="IdentityServiceWS">
    <wsdl:operation name="invokeIdentityService">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:invokeIdentityService" name="invokeIdentityService">
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:invokeIdentityServiceResponse"
            name="invokeIdentityServiceResponse">
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="identityServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:IdentityServiceWS">
    <soap:binding style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="invokeIdentityService">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document" />
        <wsdl:input name="invokeIdentityService">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="invokeIdentityServiceResponse">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="identityService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:identityServiceSoapBinding" name="IdentityServiceWSImplPort">
        <soap:address
            location="https://staging.identitymanagement.dummy.com/identity- service/services/identityServiceWS" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I was successfully able to generate the stubs and while invoking the service, i get the below error.

```
 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unbound namespace URI 'http://ns.dummy.com/identity-service/1.0'
at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SOAPMessageFormatter.writeTo(SOAPMessageFormatter.java:83)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisRequestEntity.writeRequest(AxisRequestEntity.java:84)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.writeRequestBody(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:499)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2114)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
```

How do i go about resolving this.

The wsdl given is a thrid party wsdl file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you see this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718588/code-generation-from-wsdl-causes-exception

Comment: Thanks Eker. I did saw the thread which you pointed out. Since this is a third party wsdl file, we dont have the rights to change anything. So i was looking for a work around for this issue.